# Accessing filters applied for custom kibana visualization plugin

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, plugins, kibana-4

I have a plugin which uses my own es REST service to get data and I am able to use "ui/filter_manager" to add filters to dashboard using add method as per timroes plugin:

```
filterManager.add(
            // The field to filter for, we can get it from the config
            //$scope.vis.aggs.bySchemaName['tags'][0].params.field,
             $scope.fieldName,
            // The value to filter for, we will read out the bucket key from the tag
            tag.label,
            // Whether the filter is negated. If you want to create a negated filter pass '-' here
            null,
            // The index pattern for the filter
            $scope.vis.indexPattern.title
        );
```

as on https://github.com/Prazzy/tr-k4p-tagcloud/blob/master/public/tagcloudController.js

But by this , i would be able to apply my visualization filter to dashboard but i also need to apply filters applied from other visualization onto my viz. So, what I expect is some variable 
that would be saving filters that i unable to find till now.
Or last approach could be extracting filter from browser url and firing queries as filter changes in url ???

Comment: I tried accessing   
var queryFilter = Private(require('ui/filter_bar/query_filter'));
But got blank lists for getAppFilters/getFilters/getGlobalFilters functions.

Comment: Same link on kibana forum :
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/accessing-filters-applied-for-custom-kibana-visualization-plugin/70252

Comment: Oh, If some body looking for solution on this my last comment should work ,on my part I had some controller issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
import FilterBarQueryFilterProvider from 'ui/filter_bar/query_filter';

// Somewhere in your directive, service, or controller const
queryFilter = Private(FilterBarQueryFilterProvider);
queryFilter.getFilters(); // returns array of **pinned** filters
```

The dependency gets injected on import statement from `kibana` plugin source folder (`ui/filter_bar`) and `query_filter` gave object that gave `filter_bar` filters applied on a `kibana` dashboard from `visualisation` clicks that invoked `filterManager.add()` function.